# Vue.js authentication after manually entering URL

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

In my `routes` array in `main.js`, I have set

```
meta : { requiresAuth: true }
```

for every component except on the `UserLogin` page.

Regarding navigation resolution, I have set a check before each route as follows:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
    const currentUserState = !!currentUser;

    console.table({ currentUserState, requiresAuth });

    if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
        next('/login');
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

With this setup, everything almost works as expected/intended. Logged in users can go anywhere, and anonymous users are redirected to `localhost/login`.

However, this checking and redirecting only functions when users are navigating by clicking the links in the web app (which are all `<router-link>`s that go `:to="{ name: 'SomeComponent' }"`.

When any user (registered or anonymous) attempts to navigate their way around the app by typing or copy pasting urls, the app will automatically send them to the login page.

From the console.table output, I can see that manually entering urls always results in currentUserState being false.

It does not remain false: a user that has logged in (`currentUserState === true`), who then manually navigates somewhere (`currentUserState === false`), has their `currentUserState` revert back to `true`

I can only vaguely guess that the problem is related to rendering and `firebase.auth()`.

Comment: need to see how you are initializing firebase... i would guess that you are setting up the routes before firebase is initialized so when a user enters a url the router is being called before firebase is initialized therefore there is no user

Comment: @AaronSaunders I have a database.js file where my config object lives. `app = firebase.initializeApp(confg)` happens in this file, and `db = app.database();` is exported. database.js is not called in `main.js`

Comment: `firebase.initializeApp(confg)` does not resolve the current user...

Comment: @AaronSaunders Thanks for your reply. I require clarification on what you mean by 'resolve' the current user, or rather, how to make available the ability to call `firebase.auth().currentUser` in the `router.beforeEach` callback in `main.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this bug.

In my Vuex `store.js`, a snapshot of the state is stored into localStorage. This snapshot is updated any time there is a change to the store itself, so the localStorage backup is always up-to-date with the actual state of the Vue.js application itself.

```
store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(state));
});
```

This `store.subscribe` is set in my `store.js` just before the export line.

A function called `initStore` is also defined in the store as follows

```
initStore(state) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('store')) {
    this.replaceState(Object.assign(state, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store'))));
  }
},
```

and after my store object, it is immediately called with
`store.commit('initStore')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
firebase.initializeApp(config)

// you need to let firebase try and get the auth state before instantiating the 
// the Vue component, otherwise the router will be created and you haven't 
// resolved whether or not you have a user

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      template: '<App/>',
      components: { App },
      router
    })
});
```